# iPhone data exchange using eMail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In my application I want to be able to send data to a user who can then import it into some other application - a report writer, spreadsheet, database or whatever else.

I'm looking at various techniques and would like input from the community. I intend sending an email with an attachment. The question is in what format, a tab or comma delimited file? A file of XML or .... what? The file is a representation of an NSMutableArray with some 600+ elements. I'm assuming the user doesn't have access to a relational database so SQL is not an option.

Advice and experiences greatly appreciated.

Comment: This really depends on your target application.  Every application has different file formats they can support, and new custom ones can easily be added.  I don't know that there can be a definitive answer unless you narrow down what applications you'd like to target with this.

Answer (score 0):

Comma delimited is the most importable, assuming your data can be represented in that way - XML is too generic, anything could read it but nothing would know what to do with it.